# Load images from a specific folder in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, directory, load

I need to migrate an old website's posts written in php (860 posts in total) to Wordpress. The Wp All Import plugin succesfully resolved my problem, but I have a /images folder with aproximatly 1000 images that are linked to posts. Almost all images are stored in images/uploads/vegyes-kepek
Is there a way to load automatically?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question lacks information to get any help from [so] users. Please take the [tour], and read through the [help], learn  [ask] a good question? to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions. If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [mcve] and people will be very glad to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer.